# Trying to set up a RasPi 3A, it does nothing on boot

Tags: pi-3a+

New to this, so bear with me.

I have a Raspi 3A with a 16 gb SD card. I have installed the Raspberry Pi OS (32 bit) onto it using the Raspberry Pi imager.

I have the RasPi attached to a monitor via hdmi. When I give the RasPi power, the red light turns on. The green flicks on for a half second, then turns off and stays off. The monitor never shows anything.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sounds like it is working normally. You may have monitor and/or HDMI cable problems.

Comment: I would add the ssh and wpa_supplicant files to boot as per https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md , check it shows on your router and then see if you can ssh to it

Comment: A 3A takes more than half a second to boot, but it is worth making sure anyway.  Try adding `hdmi_safe=1` to `config.txt`.  If you still get nothing all you can do is to try to install the image again, try a different card...

Comment: @Milliways This is the same monitor I use for my regular computer, and it works fine. I'm just using it on the RasPi until I can access the raspi over ssh. There is no problem in the monitor or cable.